# Do I not lose rep from downvotes when I delete an answer?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I missed what language a question was in and answered incorrectly.  One helpful comment (and several downvotes) later, I realized my mistake and deleted it.  I wasn't paying attention to my rep score, but the downvotes didn't show up on my "recent history."  Did I not lose the rep?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get the reputation back when the post is deleted.

Think of it as a reward for doing the right thing and removing incorrect information.

Comment: Sounds good.  Thanks!

Comment: @SomeKittens: Also, if you visit your reputation history, you can check the "show removed posts" checkbox all the way at the bottom. It will show all the downvotes you had received as well as a "removed" event where you got the reputation back for them after the deletion.